# Connect to mySQL server from PHP and JQuery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, mysql

Good evening SO. I'm a complete newbie when it comes to HTML, CSS, JS, PHP, and the like, so I need some help, particularly with some PHP and JQuery.

I'm trying to submit a simple email from an HTML form. Here's the HTML/ JQuery snippet of that happening:

```
<form action="" id="emailform" name="emailform">
          <input type="email" class="form-control" name="email_submit_field" id="email_submit_field" placeholder="type your email here">
          <input id="email_submit_button" class="btn btn-default" role="button" type="submit" value="Submit"></input>
</form>
<script>    
    $("form").submit(function(event){
            event.preventDefault();
            $.post("email.php", $("#emailform").serialize());
    });
</script>
```

From there, it is supposed to open up `email.php`. God knows if it is even doing that right, let me know please. But anyways, once it gets into `email.php`, it aims to post that email value to a mySQL database running on localhost. Here's the PHP I have to accomplish that:

```
<?php

$dbname = "test";
$host = "localhost";
$usr = "root";
$pass = "password"; //obviously not, but you get the point

$email = $_POST["email_submit_field"];

$cxn = new mysqli($host, $usr, $pass, $dbname);

$query = "INSERT INTO emails VALUES('$email')";
mysqli_query($query);
mysqli_close();
?>
```

The big problem that I have with all of this is that it seems like *every single* tutorial does this in a different way, **none** of which work for me. Long story short, the mySQL database never receives the data, and I have no idea why. Any and all assistance is appreciated, and hopefully someone can help me understand how (in a simple and consistent way) to access a mySQL database via PHP. Thank you in advance SO.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You forgot what column (*or table?*) your value is going to be inserted.

```
INSERT INTO emails (column_name) VALUES('$email')
```

or should it be

```
INSERT INTO table_name (emails) VALUES ('$email')
```

Check your syntax. When using `mysqli_*` like you use `mysql_*`, you should include your connection variable, which is `$cxn` in your given example, when executing a query.

```
mysqli_query($cxn, $query);
```

And also, use at least `*_real_escape_string` to sanitize the value and prevent some [SQL injections](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php).

```
$email = mysqli_real_escape_string($cxn, $_POST["email_submit_field"]);
```

But it would be better if you use [mysqli prepared statement](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php). You can refer to this:

```
if($stmt = $cxn->prepare("INSERT INTO emails (column_name) VALUES (?)")){ /* CHECK IF THE QUERY IS TRUE */
  $stmt->bind_param("s",$_POST["email_submit_field"]); /* BIND THE VARIABLE TO YOUR QUERY */
  $stmt->execute(); /* EXECUTE THE QUERY */
  $stmt->close();
}
```

And for your script, you wanted to submit the form without refreshing the page, right? Then, you should use [AJAX](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) for this case.

```
<script>    
    $(document).ready(function(){
      $("#email_submit_button").click(function(e){ /* WHEN THE BUTTON IS CLICKED OR THE FORM IS SUBMITTED */
        e.preventDefault(); /* STOP THE PAGE FROM REFRESHING */
        var email = $("#email_submit_field").val(); /* STORE THE VALUE OF THE EMAIL FIELD */
        var dataString = "email="+email; /* STORE THE EMAIL TO A DATA STRING */
        $.ajax({ /* CALL AJAX */
          type: "POST",
          url: "email.php", /* SUBMIT THE DATA TO THIS PAGE */
          data: dataString,
          success: function(data){
            $("#email_submit_field").val(""); /* EMPTY THE EMAIL FIELD */
          }
        });
        return false;
      });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Wow! This was quite the response. A few hours later, I managed to finally get it to work with a lot of assistance from this. Thanks for helping me out, especially with the AJAX part.

Answer (score 1):

You have mixed procedural functions with object orientation. And you also forgot to mark the fields on your query. I don't know how your table looks like, but I'm assuming it has one fields "Field_1".

Try this for OO style:

```
$cxn = new mysqli($host, $usr, $pass, $dbname);

$query = "INSERT INTO emails (`Field_1`) VALUES('$email')";
$cxn->query($query);
$cxn->close();
```

Or change it all to procedural

```
$cxn = mysqli_connect($host, $usr, $pass, $dbname);
if (mysqli_connect_errno($cnx)) {
   trigger_error('Database connection failed: '  . mysqli_connect_error(), E_USER_ERROR);
}
$query = "INSERT INTO emails (`Field_1`) VALUES('$email')";
$result = mysqli_query($cxn, $query)
```

More info on `mysqli` [here](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php).

Comment: I'm pretty sure binding two column fields with only one value will result to this error `Column count doesn't match value count at row 1`

Comment: No worries. And BTW, I'm not the OP.

Comment: Thanks for the response! I'm still learning PHP and all, so I'm not surprised that I managed to mix up OO and procedural. Your response was very helpful though, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to change this code:

```
mysqli_query($query);
mysqli_close();
```

to this:

```
$cxn->query($query);
```

Answer (score 0):

Found this, hope it helps:

```
// Check connection
if ($cxn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $cxn->connect_error);
} 

$sql = "INSERT INTO emails VALUES('$email')";

if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
    echo "New record created successfully";
} else {
    echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error;
}

$cxn->close();
?>
```

better explained here: http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_insert.asp